# How to fix "'.' in formula and no 'data' argument" when using randomForest function?

Tags: r, random-forest

I am trying to build a random forest regression model with my data. For the first argument I wrote the formula, then I specified the data and lastly wrote the number of desired trees.

```
rf_model = randomForest(targetVar ~., data = train, ntree = 50)
```

The Error that I am getting when executing this line of code is:

```
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
'.' in formula and no 'data' argument
```

What is causing the error? it is a very simple and straightforward implementation of the random forest regression model. Also, reading about the error hasn't yield to any valid solution.

Comment: How do you create `train` dataset? post the lines you create the dataset.

Comment: I simply read it as a csv file: train <- read.csv('Downloads/train.csv', sep = ',')

Comment: Ok cool, what does `colnames(train)` print?

Comment: oh I just noticed it prints Null!! why is that?

Comment: I see, the data frame hasn't been loaded correctly.

Comment: Do you mean there is something wrong with importing the data? but I have been doing the preprocessing steps with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the `randomForest` function. It's with the `train` dataset and how you instruct `randomForest` to process it.

1. You have to instruct `randomForest()` to how to handle `NA` values. For example, you have to set `na.action=na.omit`.
2. Your dataset has too many variables - randomForest complains 53 variables is too many.

So as an example, I'll show you how to get it working with a 2 variables.

```
train <- read.csv('<path to>/Train.csv', header=TRUE, sep = ",")
sales <- randomForest(Item_Outlet_Sales~Item_MRP+Item_Weight, data = train, ntree=50, na.action=na.omit)
sales
```

The `na.omit` is not the only function available. Please see the documentation for more NA handling functions.

You have to see what variables you want to use. Hope this helps.